# IntelliJ spaces around assignment operator in annotation

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way to prevent my IDE from puting space around assignment operator inside annotations?

Consider following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "name", defaultValue = "Anonym")
```

To be formatted as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="name", defaultValue="Anonym")
```

Without spaces around assignment operator. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off

Code Style => Java => Spaces => Around Operators => Assignment Operators

Note: this changes all assignment operators, not just annotations.

Comment: Here is the feature request to control it separately in the annotations: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5040.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Ouh. Then I have to wait for it.